# How to cast an EF4.1 table class to a derived view class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have used Entity Framework and have generated edmx for my db. The generated template classes represent each table. I have a generated class 'Table' from which I have copied 4 out of it's 12 properties to a new interface 'ITableModel'.

```
var tables = (from t in db.Tables 
                        orderby t.DateReceived descending
                        select t).Take(100);

var list = tables.AsEnumerable().Cast<ITableModel>().ToList();
```

As you can proobably guess, the cast throws an invalidcast exception. The goal here is to prune out the info I need to pass to my views (MVC3) and create view classes that represent that information. From what I have gathered, this is the best practice, but I am against a wall with this casting. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I had a deleted comment point me to automapper... would this work for me?

Comment: @Nathan has deleted his post. The idea of using Automapper was correct but queries must be written in different way. Automapper must be used after loading entities.

Comment: Ah, gotcha... I am going to be using your approach - It requires more work up front but will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need all data from Table then there is no need to transfer them from database. You can use:

```
public class MyProjection : ITableModel
{
     public int SomeField { get; set; }
     public string SomeField2 { get; set; }
}
```

And call your query as:

```
var list =  db.Tables 
              .OrderByDescending(t => t.DateReceived)
              .Take(100) 
              .Select(t => new MyProjection 
                   {
                       SomeField = t.SomeField,
                       SomeField2 = t.SomeField2
                   })
              .ToList();
```

`Cast` is possible only if you override operator for casting but it requires concrete type because operator must create instance of the target type.

Comment: Ladislav, thank you for you answer! Can you clarify this please: "only if you override operator for casting"? - I will be doing this for hundreds of tables and would hate to have to manually assign columns to object properties (I have LINQ in ActionResults all over!)

Comment: If you want to optimize loading you have indeed do it manually for every table.